# Installing GRPC in Windows

Tags: go, grpc

I simply write the following code to the CMD,

`set PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"`

and don't know whether I do something sensible or not.

I just replaced `expose` with `set` because of Windows.

What should be done next to complete the installation successfully?

Could you provide how you would install it as if it were your PC as a raw string without any shell variable? Because I'm not comfortable with Shell yet.

Comment: You're following the instructions on https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/ ? That's written for unix (although it doesn't say so). I'm not an expert on windows, but I think you need to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone who comes here:

- first of all, you should download the latest version of the protocol buffer:

  download from [this link](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/latest) and install the version that you want, like: `protoc-3.19.3-win64.zip`

  after that add the binary path that you installed on the path environment. ( for more information about adding to path environment see [this link](http://add-windows-path-environment-variable))
- after that you need to install the proto compiler for the language you want. in this example I choose `go`:

> $ go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.26
> $ go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.1

**Note:** The `GOPATH` should be in environments. also `GOPATH/bin`.